# Read INI file parameters

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, scripting

I have an INI file with the following configuration:

```
[Applications]
app1= aplication1
app2= aplication2

[BBDD]
server_bbdd = name_bbdd

[DATA]
data_dir = c:\data\

[LOGS]
data_log = c:\data\log\
```

I need to read and load the application data with my PowerShell script. For example for app1 I need to load all the data of this app into the database (is a SQL-SERVER BBDD) and then do the same for app2.

What can I do to read and load the application data with PowerShell?

Comment: *for app1 I need to load all the data of this app into the database* What "all data"? From where? Into what database? Which table? Parsing an INI file is simple enough, but you didn't provide enough information for anyone to even guess at how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with ini file like with hashes and create a hash table and put them into variables.
e.g.
$Applications = @{“app1”=”aplication1”;“app2”=”aplication2”}

This read-to-use function will read ini file and separate those parts taht are section names from sections values.
We read it to a hash that is in the memory, you'll need it to output later.
"switch -regex" is used to handle multiple if statements.
-regex       Treat the match clause, if a string, as a Regex (regular expression, i.e. RegEx characters: ^ . [ ] - g G ? + * p P w W s S d D $).

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
    {
        $ini = @{}
        switch -regex -file $FilePath
        {
            "^\[(.+)\]" # Find Sections
            {
                $section = $matches[1]
                $ini[$section] = @{}
                $CommentCount = 0
            }
            "^(;.*)$" # Find Comments
            {
                $value = $matches[1]
                $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
                $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount
                $ini[$section][$name] = $value
            } 
            "(.+?)\s*=(.*)" # Find Keys
            {
                $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
                $ini[$section][$name] = $value
            }
        }
        return $ini
    }
```

After that you can read it to variables and hence, output these variables to a file or something.

```
$iniContent = Get-IniContent “c:\temp\file.ini”
$iniContent[“Applications”]
$value = $iniContent[“Applications”][“app1”]
$iniContent[“Applications”].Keys | %{$iniContent["Applications"][$_]}
```

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ea40c1ef-c856-434b-b8fb-ebd7a76e8d91